# how to run win exe by python subprocess with a absolutely path?

Tags: python

The win .exe format is `D:\test\my.exe -a .\ini\some.ini` under win cmd line shell.

`-a` indicates output is text format.

`.ini\` is relative path to `my.exe`.

So how use subprocess call this executation?

I tried as follows but error:

```
subprocess.call([r'D:\test\my.exe','-a','.\ini\some.ini'])
```

Comment: could you include the full traceback?

Comment: What error do you get when running this? Also do you want to just run this or do you want to get the output of the operation?

Comment: Your third string seems to contain unescaped characters which might cause a problem in running your command the way you intended it.

Comment: It could run I tried again! Actually the exe carry out half  because lack of file. It  run until display  error under win cmd. But carried in python,the shell flash close and return '1'  ,that I didn't know what happen.

Comment: Add trace back to improve this question!

Answer (score 1):

It will be confusing to use rel path here.

In python you can convert relative path to absolute path by using.

```
import os
cur_path = os.path.realpath('.')
```

You can also join the path like.

```
final_path = os.path.join(cur_path, 'ini', 'some.ini')
```

Answer (score 0):

Only your first string is marked as raw. You either need to mark all strings as raw where you have backslashes:

```
subprocess.call([r'D:\test\my.exe', '-a', r'.\ini\some.ini'])
```

or escape your backslashes:

```
subprocess.call(['D:\\test\\my.exe', '-a', '.\\ini\\some.ini'])
```

Answer (score 0):

the code:

```
subprocess.call([r'D:\test\my.exe','-a','.\ini\some.ini'])
```

above code is right. The problem is cmd .exe executed lack of file at the last processing. So the subprocess return value '1' and the cmd shell flash off that I can't find the mistake.
It look like that the `subprocess` return '0' unless cmd .exe carry out perfectly.